# How to create subindex efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, running-count

I would like to create a subindex for my dataframe based on the index. For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
      Content        Date
ID                       
Bob  birthday  2010.03.01
Bob    school  2010.04.01
Tom  shopping  2010.02.01
Tom      work  2010.09.01
Tom   holiday  2010.10.01
```

I'd like create a subindex for for my `ID` and the resulting dataframe looks like below:

```
               Content        Date
ID  subindex                      
Bob 1         birthday  2010.03.01
    2           school  2010.04.01
Tom 1         shopping  2010.02.01
    2             work  2010.09.01
    3          holiday  2010.10.01
```

To do this I need to first create my `subindex` list. I searched in the help document and it seems to most neat way is to use `transform`:

```py
subindex = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x) + 1))
```

However, it is really slow. I looked around and found `apply` can do the work too:

```py
subindex = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x) + 1))
```

Of course the `subindex` needed to be flattened since it is a list of lists here. This works much faster than the `transform` method. Then I tested with a `for loop` of my own:

```py
subindex_size = df.groupby(df.index, sort = False).size()
subindex = []
for i in np.arange(len(subindex_size)):
    subindex.extend(np.arange(1,subindex_size[i]+1))
```

It's even faster. With my larger dataset (about 90k rows), the `transform` method takes about 44 secs on my computer, `apply` takes ~2 secs and the `for loop` takes only ~1 secs. I need to work on much larger dataset so even the time difference between the `apply` and `for loop` makes a difference to me. However, the `for loop` looks ugly and may not be easily applied if I need to create other group-based variables.

So my question is, why the built-in functions that are supposed to do the right thing are slower? Am I missing something here or is there a reason for this? Is there any other way to improve this process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) to do this:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
Out[11]: 
ID
Bob    0
Bob    1
Tom    0
Tom    1
Tom    2
dtype: int64

In [12]: df['subindex'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()  # possibly + 1 here.

In [13]: df.set_index('subindex', append=True)
Out[13]: 
               Content        Date
ID  subindex                      
Bob 0         birthday  2010.03.01
    1           school  2010.04.01
Tom 0         shopping  2010.02.01
    1             work  2010.09.01
    2          holiday  2010.10.01
```

*To start at 1 (rather than 0) just add 1 to the result of cumcount.*